# selecting a range of colums in SKlearn column transformer

Tags: encoding, one-hot-encoding

I am encoding catagorical data, many columns need to be seletced, I have typed them in individually and it works ok but there is obviouly a more elegant way.

```
dataset =pd.read_csv('train.csv')
x = dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values
    
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
    from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
    ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(),[2,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,21,22,23,24,25,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,39,40,41,42,53,54,55,56,57,58,60,63,64,65,72,73,74,78,79])], remainder='passthrough')
    x = np.array(ct.fit_transform(x))
```

I have tried using (23:34) I have tried using slice but that does not work as it is not that data type.

Which method should I use for selecting a range of columns?

Also what datatype is it at this point were I am selecting the columns?

I made a search I an not able to see a solution for this exact question.

Finally, is this an effecient way to encode catagorical data or should I be looking at an alternative method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following workaround:

```
ct = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("ordinal_enc", OrdinalEncoder(), data.loc[:, "col1":"col100"].columns)
    ])
```